# Array returning as undefined - Dependency Injection? Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I assign an array data received from an endpoint.

I try to call this array in another file and it doesn't like it!
My subsidiaryNames array consoles correctly.

My first file:

```
export class EngagementService {
    public orgSubSidNames = [];


    let subsidiaryNames = []
    data.forEach(sub => {
        console.log(sub.SubsidiaryName)
        subsidiaryNames.push(sub.SubsidiaryName)
    })
    subsidiaryNames = subsidiaryNames.filter(this.onlyUnique);
    console.log('subsidiary name array' + subsidiaryNames)
    this.orgSubSidNames = subsidiaryNames;

    // This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

    if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
        of_beautifier();
    } else {
        var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
    }
```

Second File:

```
export class EngagementFilterComponent implements OnInit {
    public subSidNameArray: EngagementService;


    updateSub(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('attempting to print the subsid array' + this.subSidNameArray.orgSubSidNames)
    }
```

I get the error:

```
 Cannot read property 'orgSubSidNames' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you import first file in second file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that creates `EngagementFilterComponent`

```
const filter = new EngagementFilterComponent()
filter.subSidNameArray = new EngagementService()
```

or set it in constructor

```
public subSidNameArray: EngagementService = new EngagementService()
```

or use injection

If your framework uses injection, make sure your receiving component uses a proper constructor. `constructor(private engagementService: EngagementService)`

## Explanation

The line

```
 public subSidNameArray: EngagementService
```

declares that your class contains an instance of  `EngagementService`.  You have not created one yet.  An instance of the class must be created using the `new` keyword.  The `:EngagementService` part is `typescript` for declaring the type that `subSidNameArray` is, a feature not found in ordinary `javascript`. It does not create an instance though.

Comment: Thank you it worked, could you or somebody please explain to me why the data is accessible from a constructor but not if i declare it as i did just within the class? is it because I am creating a new variable in the class so it will be empty? From the constructor it must somehow access the original values?

Comment: @Sparlarva I will add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: I noticed my engagementService class has an '@injectable' above it

Comment: If the class is `injectable`, the framework should be injecting the member.  Keep in mind a class must be constructed before its members are injected, or as parameters to the construction.

Comment: My constructor has:  constructor( public engagementService: EngagementService) I can call on this engagementService and it can act on the data, so that's the dependency injection?

Comment: I don't see the constructor in your example....  Try `this.subSidNameArray = engagementService` in your constructor.  It seems you are getting the injection, but not assigning it to your member.

Answer (score 2):

You never set the value of your property `public subSidNameArray: EngagementService;`

Answer (score 1):

`subSidNameArray` needs to be initialized somewhere, not just declared. As others have answered, you can make an explicit assignment to it with `new EngagementService()`, but if you use Angular, the "correct" way to do it would be to use dependecy injection (DI) in your second file:

```
constructor(private engagementService: EngagementService) {...}
```

Make sure that your `EngagementService` is injectable, by adding the `@Injectable` decorator before the class declaration:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EngagementService {
  ...
}
```

Comment: So within the constructor, it's called dependency injection and that way carries over the data from the second file? Not having the variable in the constructor but just within the class is basically something new?

Comment: Yes, if you put the services in the constructor parameters, it's called dependency injection (DI). Just having the variable in the class without assigning it anything just means that the variable is of type `EngagementService`, but it has no value. When you assign it, it gets a value which means that you can use it. DI is a way to let Angular handle the assignment. This will give you a lot of benefits during development, like when unit testing, but that's a lesson for another day ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! I wish I started using this website a long time ago, my learning has been much more rapid. Haha, well I'm always in need of lessons!

Comment: You're welcome =) I should add that the `providedIn: 'root'` is what says that Angular shouldn't create a new instance every time there is a component that uses it, but rather use the same instance. In other words, `EngagementService` becomes a "singleton". You can read more about Angular DI here https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection